Why is the form of the verb "to be" used after conjuction "and"?
Here is one sentence:

It is one of the biggest and most fascinating caves in the world and is the only cave in Russia that has been adapted for tourist excursion.

Might I write like this?

It is one of the biggest and most fascinating caves in the world and the only cave in Russia that has been adapted for tourist excursion.

What is the sense of "is" after conjuction "and"?

There is no to be after and in your sentence.

The word is in your example is just an optional repetition / "deletion" of the parallel construction (two sentences joined by and). But as well as the verb, you've also "deleted" the subject (it) ...and it is the only cave in Russia...


It [is one of the biggest and most fascinating caves in the world] and [is the only cave in Russia that has been adapted for tourist excursion].

The sentence is fine.  The brackets show the parallelism.
We can shift the brackets:

It is [one of the biggest and most fascinating caves in the world] and [the only cave in Russia that has been adapted for tourist excursion].

This is the OP’s suggestion; it saves one word and is my preference.
The is is a copula commonly used in such a construction:
Subject + Copula + Subject Complement
Here the subject is elided:
... (it) is the only cave ...
